# 3 programs, one post, can I delete the ones that don't match the title?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

in this question

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59586/18427

the OP has posted 3 programs and has been told to post separate questions, would it be acceptable for me to edit the question to the code that does what the title says (and the tags)?

Comment: @anyone if above is discouraged, please specify what would be better... DV? VTC as Too Board? Review it anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would choose to close it as "Unclear what you are asking", or maybe "Too broad", but it doesn't really matter what the exact closure reason is.  The OP was advised long ago to ask separate questions, but chose to leave the question in this unanswerable state.  Given the lack of effort and cooperation, I have little sympathy.